# Help with finding critical values of multi-variable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I'm not sure what are my critical values since I end up with multiple x and y values.

My given equation: $z = 3x - x^{3} - 2y^{2} + y^{4}$

Set $z_x = 0$ :

$3-3x^{2} = 0 => 1 - x^{2} = 0 => x^{2} = 1 => x = 1, -1$

Set $z_y = 0$ :

$-4y + 4y^{3} = 0 => -y + y^{3} = 0 => y^{3} - y = 0 => y(y^{2} - 1) = 0 => y = 0, 1, -1$

I'm not sure which pair of values are the critical values, since there are 2 x's and 3 y's.

Comment: Sounds like you have 6 critical points (not values).

Comment: @TedShifrin For multi-variable functions, are critical points usually not made of an x and y value? Because I know in another function, they take the same steps as me and end up with one x and one y value which is there critical point (x, y)

Comment: Yes, of course. How many ordered pairs do you get?

Comment: @TedShifrin So it would be: (1, 0) (1, -1) (1, 1) (-1, 0) (-1, 1) (-1, -1)? :O